# JQ: Convert Dictionary with List as Values to flat CSV

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv

#### Original Data

I have the following JSON:

```json
{
    "foo":[
        "asd",
        "fgh"
    ],
    "bar":[
        "abc",
        "xyz",
        "ert"
    ],
    "baz":[
        "something"
    ]
}
```

Now I want to transform it to a "flat" CSV, such that for every key in my object the list in the value is expanded to `n` rows with `n` being the number of entries in the respective list.

#### Expected Output

```
foo;asd
foo;fgh
bar;abc
bar;xyz
bar;ert
baz;something
```

### Approaches

I guess I need to use `to_entries` and then **for each** `.value` repeat the same `.key` for the first column. The [jq docs state](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Advancedfeatures) that:

> Thus `as` functions as something of a foreach loop.

So I tried combining

- `to_entries`to give the keys and values from my dictionary an accessible name
- then build kind of a foreach loop around the `.value`s
- and pass the result to `@csv`

`to_entries|map(.value) as $v|what goes here?|@csv`

I prepared something that at least compiles [here](https://jqplay.org/s/xZ_FCxVD5H)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need to use _entries function, a simple key/value lookup and string interpolation should suffice

```
keys_unsorted[] as $k | "\($k);\( .[$k][])"
```

The construct `.[$k][]` is an expression that first expands the value associated with each key, i.e. `.foo` and then with [object construction](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D), produces multiple results for each key identified and stored in `$k` variable.

Comment: Initially I had problems understanding your answer because I thought, "keys_unsorted" refered to some kind of data. Didn't know it was a [builtin function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions). Maybe you could add a comment about this. ALso here's jqplay link with your example: https://jqplay.org/s/SfCs8Y5zN5